# Error in WordPress with plugin reactpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using WordPress version 5.7.2 and when I upgrade it to php version 7.4.19 I get these errors:

Failed opening 'default' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php7.4') wp-includes/template-loader.php on line 106

Warning: include(default): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /homepages/1/d229455270/htdocs/clickandbuilds/WordPress/DaseCMS/wp-includes/template-loader.php on line 106

This happens when I activate the plugin reactpress. This is the piece of code where the error occurs:

```
/**
* Filters the path of the current template before including it.
*
* @since 3.0.0
*
* @param string $template The path of the template to include.
*/
    $template = apply_filters( 'template_include', $template );
    if ( $template ) {
        include $template;  //Error in this line
    } elseif ( current_user_can( 'switch_themes' ) ) {
        $theme = wp_get_theme();
    if ( $theme->errors() ) {
        wp_die( $theme->errors() );
    }
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix it? I see that is compatible with my WordPress version...

[image]

And with my php version...

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Looks like this is not a WordPress error. You can also try this. https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-wordpress-failed-to-open-stream-error/

Comment: @Xim123 When you deactivate this plugin the problem does fix?

Comment: yes, it fix the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

Because there's a mistake in the `Reactpress_Public::repr_change_page_template()` method (see [line 99 in `wp-content/plugins/reactpress/public/class-reactpress-public.php`](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/reactpress/tags/1.2.0/public/class-reactpress-public.php#L99)) which is [hooked](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/reactpress/tags/1.2.0/includes/class-reactpress.php#L180) onto [`template_include`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/).

The author should check if the value of the `_wp_page_template` metadata (which stores the path of a [custom page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use)) is **not** `default` (which is the default value) and only if so, then should the `$template` value be set to the metadata value.

And if one doesn't do that check, then we'd end up with `include 'default'` which then emits the error/warning in question ("Failed opening 'default' for inclusion").

> How can I fix it?

Please contact the plugin support and ask them to fix the issue ASAP, but for the time being, you may just change the [conditional here](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/reactpress/tags/1.2.0/public/class-reactpress-public.php#L103) to: (* change the entire "if")

```php
if (!empty($meta['_wp_page_template'][0]) && $meta['_wp_page_template'][0] != $template && // wrapped
    'default' !== $meta['_wp_page_template'][0] // check if the value is NOT "default"
) {
    $template = $meta['_wp_page_template'][0];
}
```

*Yes, you shouldn't modify core plugin files; but this is a special case, because the plugin needs a fix, which hopefully will come in the plugin's next release.*

#### Alternate solution without modifying the plugin files

.. is by overriding the template using the same hook:

```php
// Add to the theme functions.php file:
add_filter( 'template_include', 'my_fix_template_include', 100 );
function my_fix_template_include( $template ) {
    if ( 'default' === $template && is_page() ) { // * the plugin uses is_page()
        $template = get_page_template();
    }

    return $template;
}
```

Comment: so I have to add this piece of code at the end of the functions.php file and remove the line include $template by my_fix_template_include($template) ?

Comment: Yes, you can add it to `functions.php` (in your theme), but please don't modify core WordPress files like the `wp-includes/template-loader.php` - so **no**, don't remove the `include $template;` from that core file !

Comment: okay, so if I understood it well I just need to add this piece of code in functions.php of my theme right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Although I might rather fix the plugin filter by editing the `if` block in the [file](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/reactpress/tags/1.2.0/public/class-reactpress-public.php#L103) (`wp-content/plugins/reactpress/public/class-reactpress-public.php`) I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Plugin creator here. Thank for your awesome answer. I released a new plugin version based on your work today.